# Entropy $dQ=TdS$ and Work $dW = -pdV$ conditions?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, work

What are the conditions in order for the equations: [Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) $dQ = TdS$ and [Work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28thermodynamics%29) $dW = -p dV$  to work?

I think for $dQ = T dS$, it must be a reversible process?

But for $dW = -p dV$, shouldn't it always hold?

Comment: The identity that does always hold is: dE = T dS - p dV. For quasistatic changes this is clearly true, but because E is a state function of S and V, this must be always true. It then follows that if dQ is not T dS, then -p dV  cannot possibly be equal to the work performed on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think for $dQ = T dS$, it must be a reversible process?

Yes.

> But for $dW = -p dV$, shouldn't it always hold?

No, it is only for reversible Pressure-Volume work.  It doesn't apply to irreversible processes.  It does not apply to situations with other types of work like electrical, surface tension, etc.

According to Physical Chemistry by Levine, "work in a mechanical irreversible volume change sometimes cannot be calculated by thermodynamics".  Non-uniform pressure, turbulence and kinetic energy are then discussed.

Answer (score 6):

> I think for $dQ = T dS$, it must be a reversible process?

Not necessarily. It has to be quasistatic process in which the system passes through equilibrium states. Quasistatic process in theory may be reversible, but need not be. For example, when heat passes from colder body to warmer body through separating insertion (walls) slowly enough so that the bodies remain near equilibrium state, for any one body the relation $dQ=TdS$ holds, where $T$ is temperature of this body. This process is irreversible, since heat is going from warmer to colder body, but the formula applies for both bodies separately. Only for the combined system, the formula does not apply; the combined system does not have one temperature.

> But for $dW = -p dV$, shouldn't it always hold?

Again, it holds if the process is quasistatic and the system has the same pressure throughout.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused now. Do they require reversible processes or not?

Comment: Find out what "reversible process" means. It is a very special kind of process. The formula $dQ=TdS$ applies whenever the system passes through equilibrium states. The latter process is not necessarily reversible.

Comment: The process must be reversible. Remember: $$dQ_\mathrm{rev} = TdS$$.

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas Did you read my answer? I explain there why the physical process need not be reversible for the formula $dQ = TdS$  to be applicable.

Comment: @JánLalinský I checked again the Clausius inequality and your answer made sense. For two systems (hot and cold) the change in entropy of the total (isolated) system, by applying Clausius inequality for both of them, reads: $$dS \geq \left( \frac{1}{T_\mathrm{c}} - \frac{1}{T_\mathrm{h}} \right) dq $$ Your answer implies that we can drop the inequality sign. Does this happen when we have no entropy generation during the process (no hot spots in either system, only entropy transfer)?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas First, my point was that $dQ= TdS$ holds for the system which is in all its parts at the same temperature, even if it undergoes a process which is (looking at the whole supersystem) irreversible. To your question, yes, if the heat transfer is slow enough and both subsystems have uniform temperatures (which need not be the same), the inequality can be approximated by equality. As you suggest, there is no appreciable generation of entropy in the subsystems if the heat transfer is quasi-static; all entropy is generated in the wall that passes through the heat between the systems.

Comment: @JánLalinský So, every quasi-static process that is *irreversible* must have some sort of "mass flow/transfer" going on then? Also, if $\delta Q < TdS$ then an irreversible isochoric ($\delta W = 0$) process with *no* mass transfer could have $dU = TdS > \delta Q$ suggesting that internal energy could increase by *more* than the heat provided! Which seems to violate energy conservation, does that mean $dU = TdS$ only applies to quasi-static processes instead?

Comment: @ManRow no, I didn't say there has to be a mass flow. Weak heat flow through a bad heat conductor, from one temperature to a different one, is an example of quasistatic process that is not reversible.

Comment: @ManRow that's a reason for why in a process with zero work done, if temperature stays defined, the relation $TdS = dQ$ can be true even if the process is irreversible (such as income of heat from a hotter body).

Comment: @JánLalinský Sure, but doesn't a process have to be quasistatic *in order for* $T_{sys}$ to be well-defined in the first place? Otherwise, how can we compared $\delta Q$ and $TdS$ to begin with? For example, if an isochoric chamber at $T_i$ is connected to a heat bath of $T_f \gg T_i$, the flow of heat is irreversible, non-quasistatic, and should transfer $Q = nC_v(T_f-T_i)$ while creating $\Delta S = nR\ln(T_f/T_i)$ entropy.

Comment: @JánLalinský But, then we cannot claim isochoric $dU = TdS$ since $U = T_f\Delta S > Q$ would violate the first law of thermodynamics (we cannot increase $U$ by somehow "more" than just $Q$!). So, this seems to *violate* the isochoric "requirement" that $dU = TdS$, unless perhaps "$dU = TdS$" only applies when $T$ is the same everywhere? (inside the system, on the boundary of the system, and in the currently connected heat bath? But wouldn't that mean the process would have to be quasistatic then?)

Comment: @JánLalinský Or, perhaps does $dU = TdS$ *only* apply for reversible isochoric processes where $\delta Q = TdS$, while an *irreversible* isochoric *always* has some $\delta W \ne 0$ *somewhere*? Then the $W$ term in $U = Q+W$ can **never** be zero for an irreversible process, even for an *"isochoric"* one (even though it would be strange to say $\delta W = -P_{ext}dV$ since $dV = 0$ everywhere, so we'd have to say $\delta W =$ <something-else> instead). However, this still seems strange, it means irreversible isochoric processes don't *only* just add $Q$, but *also* then some $W\ne 0$ as well?

Comment: @ManRow Well I think it's obvious that $dU = TdS$ can't hold when $T$ isn't defined. It holds when the process goes through states all of which have $T,S$ defined. This has nothing to do with reversibility, it has everything to do with the process being ideal, quasistatic, so these quantities are defined so internal energy at all stages is given by the function $U(S,V)$.

Comment: @ManRow I don't see from your comments what in my answer you don't understand. Maybe post a new question.

Comment: @JánLalinský Ahh, you've answered my question here [in this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111091/entropy-dq-tds-and-work-dw-pdv-conditions/111125?noredirect=1#comment1796890_111125); that $dU = TdS$ requires ideal, quasi-static circumstances in order to hold true...

Comment: ... which, like you said earlier in [your reply to Antonios Sarikas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111091/entropy-dq-tds-and-work-dw-pdv-conditions/111125?noredirect=1#comment1626871_111125),  *"As you suggest, there is no appreciable generation of entropy in the subsystems if the heat transfer is quasi-static; all entropy is generated in the wall that passes through the heat between the systems"*